# Programmatically trigger Dialpad buttons during call

Tags: android, call, android-permissions

Is it possible to programmatically trigger dialpad buttons during running calls? This functionality will be running (of course) on the devices, which will be allowed to do this function. Do I need some permissions (not just for opening dialpad)? Or If I'll create my own dialpad small app, will this be working?

We just need to send pressed dialpad buttons during call to the server (like code).